# Eclipse Kepler don't load workspace after a crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows

I was working, with  my Eclipse Kepler, on an android project saved on my usb pendrive.
After standby the PC eclipse has crashed and when I try to open it I can see the editor with my project but the program start not responding and the progress of "bulding workspace" freeze at 67%.
What I can do to  recover my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your workspace folder and delete your .metadata folder. Works most of the time for me. You might want to test if you're able to use another workspace first and create a backup before you delete it.

Doing this will delete any customization/user data you have there like Saros account/git credentials, eclipse preferences for that workspace, etc..

It works for me most of the time. It's a quick-nasty workaround, but it works.